# Can I hide my true IP to Cisco Anyconnect with a second VPN?

Tags: vpn

I want to connect to a Cisco Anyconnect VPN (which I believe does NOT act as a proxy -- my IP address doesn't change when connecting to this VPN).

However I wish to hide my true IP to the Cisco Anyconnect server I'm connecting to.

Can I connect to another VPN service like TunnelBear first, then connect to the Cisco Anyconnect server, and be sure the Cisco Anyconnect server is seeing my TunnelBear proxy IP and not my real IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you are describing should be possible, using the technology you described. I would assume the sequence of events would follow:

1. Initiate OpenVPN connection
2. Initiate Cisco VPN connection

However, keep in mind that you may need to install a client to access the Cisco VPN. These clients tend to interact with and potentially manipulate your operating system's network configuration, this makes sense when you consider that these applications are built to re-route your network traffic. These clients would most likely have the ability to see your VPN configuration.

A possible workaround to the issues outlined above, regarding the local client being able to recognize your network configuration: one might configure their host's entire gateway (router or perhaps virtual machine host) to route traffic through the primary VPN.

You should keep in mind the resource usage and computation power required in order to maintain each VPN's security and (possibly) compression layers.

Even if the second VPN connection is established, I wouldn't expect quality performance, and multiple compression layers could be suboptimal.